# create a GitLab git repository using command line

Tags: git, curl, github

I had a script to create a git repository from command line in GitHub,
so my problem is when I try to use my script to create a new repo in GitLab, my script doesn't work !

```
repo_name=$1

dir_name=`basename $(pwd)`

if [ "$repo_name" = "" ]; then echo "Repo name (hit enter to use '$dir_name')?"  read repo_name fi

if [ "$repo_name" = "" ]; then repo_name=$dir_name fi

username="xxxxxx" if [ "$username" = "" ];  then echo "Could not find username, run 'git config --global github.user <username>'" invalid_credentials=1 fi

token="xxxxxxxx" if [ "$token" = "" ];  then echo "Could not find token, run 'git config --global github.token <token>'"  invalid_credentials=1 fi

echo -n "Creating Github repository '$repo_name' ..."  curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"'$repo_name'"}' > /dev/null 2>&1 echo " done."

echo -n "Pushing local code to remote ..."  git remote add origin git@github.com:$username/$repo_name.git > /dev/null 2>&1 git push -u origin master > /dev/null 2>&1  echo " done."
```

so what the equivalent of this

> curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d
>   '{"name":"'$repo_name'"}'

in GitLab?

thank's for your reading!

Comment: Hello! What exactly doesn't work, what is the specific error you've got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=<your token> -d "{ \"name\": \"<new repo name>\" }"` (replace gitlab url with url to your server instance)

Comment: Thank's bro for your solution